# Is it possible for a reaction to change its order mid-reaction?

Tags: kinetics

I encountered a problem which stated that the order of the reaction remained zero, until the concentration was halved. Then it became first order. Already, zero ordered reactions don't actually exist (We can create conditions though, such as the ones in the Haber process for ammonia). Changing of a zero order into first is a bit perplexing.

Comment: Autocatalytic reactions could well do this, but I can't provide a definitive example

Comment: [Changing the order of the reaction with change in concentration](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112256); [Can a first order reaction change to a second order reaction under specific temperatures?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61733)

Comment: "Saturated" photolytic reaction with all active light absorbed ( and the volume being mixed) may be the zeroth order, not depending on concentration. But when the reactant is disappearing and the active light partly  passes through, the photolysis rate would become depending on the reactant concentration.

Answer (score 2):

An example might be the Lindemann scheme for gas phase 'unimolecular' reactions such as the isomerisation $\ce{CH2NC\to CH3CN}$. The scheme is

$$\displaystyle A+M\overset{k_2}{\underset{k_{-2}}{\rightleftharpoons}} A^* +M; \qquad A^*\overset{k_1}\to P$$

where A is the reactive molecule and M a collision partner. A$^*$ is an energised molecule that undergoes reaction and P is product. Using the steady state approximation the rate of formation of product can be found but we do not necessarily need to do this.

If we assume that the rate of reaction of A$^*$ to form product is slow ($k_1$ small) relative to the equilibrium rate constants (left hand above which is forming A$^*$), this equilibrium can be satisfied and the reaction to form the product will be first order because there is always a sufficient amount of A$^*$ to react without disturbing the equilibrium.

At low pressures, on the other hand,  the equilibrium cannot be maintained i.e.  A$^*$ is formed very slowly w.r.t. its reaction to form product, and now the reaction of A$^*$ depends on how quickly it is formed, not on how quickly it reacts to form product, and so the reaction is bimolecular.